# Checking for 'null'

Tags: c#, null, nullreferenceexception, convention

Does `C#` has some rule of thumb or a coding convention contract, which handles **the possible `null` argument?**

As an example, I'm writing a custom method, which retrieves a `byte[] data` parameter.

```
public static string ConvertDataToMyOwnAndCustomString(byte[] data) { ... }
```

---

**Now - what should I do if the passed `data` is `null`?**

Should I leave it as it is so that a possible `NullReferenceException` occurs? Or should I write a check and do something like this:

```
if (data == null) return null;
```

Comment: It truly depends on your needs. does returning null make sense? if not throw an exception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generally accepted pattern is to throw an `ArgumentNullException`

```
if(data == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("data"); }
```

if it is indeed an error for clients to be passing `null` to your method. These days, you can even enforce the requirement through a Code Contract:

```
Contract.Requires(data != null);
```

Of course, it *might* very well be the case that `null` is not an error for your method. That's for you to decide though, not us. But don't return `null` to indicate to your client that an error occurred.

Comment: So, basically, all my public methods should check **all** their parameters for `nullity`? This introduces a lot of boilerplate...

Comment: @Yippie-Kai-Yay: If it is an error, yes, you should be checking for `null`. Fail fast. Don't introduce other bugs because you fail to check for `null` when you should be. Additionally, you can document to your clients that requirement by using Code Contracts. That's not boilerplate, that's valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most common pattern is:

```
if(data == null) 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

It really all depends.  Where does this method live?  How often will it be reused?  Is it only for this application, or is it part of a code library that will be utilized again?

If it is going to be used, especially by other applications/developers then I would still test for data being `null`, but then I would throw an exception.  You don't want it to choke silently.

If this is a one-off method that is for code that will surely never be reused or revisited, you could just test for `null` and return `null`.  Remember, though, this is only appropriate because you know of the outcome.  If there is any chance some other application will use this, or another developer, I'd test for `null` then throw an exception (most likely an `ArgumentNullException`).

Answer (score 1):

Jason and Christopher's answers are correct. I just want to add to them;

If it is likely and not an exceptional condition that you could get `null` for that parameter, you should not throw an exception, but instead return an appropriate value - very often, `null` itself works.

For example, with some systems of model binding, a missing text value might result in a `null` being passed as a parameter. Such an occurrence might be an error, but not an 'exceptional' one.